# Why doesn't my function load new class name on second click?

Tags: javascript

I have a modal with my function attached:

```
<img onclick="modalZoom()" class="zoomed-out" id="modal-img">
```

My function looks like this:

```
function modalZoom() {
    var imgClass = document.getElementById("modal-img").classList;
    var pedImg = document.getElementById("modal-img");
    if (imgClass = "zoomed-out") {
        pedImg.classList.remove("zoomed-out");
        pedImg.classList.add("zoomed-in");
    } else {
        pedImg.classList.remove("zoomed-in");
        pedImg.classList.add("zoomed-out");
    }
    console.log(imgClass);
}
```

I also tried adding an `else if` statement instead of just `else`, but my problem is, when I click it the first time, it reads the class and since it is `zoomed-out`, it removes that and adds `zoomed-in`. But for some reason, when I click on it the second time, the `console.log(imgClass);` still returns `zoomed-out` and the last half of my code doesn't run, even though I can see in my inspector that the class IS `zoomed-in`. Does the `var imgClass` only run the first time the function is run and if so, how do I get around it? I tried deleting the variables and getting the class directly in the `if` statement, but I still had the same problem.

Comment: `imgClass = "zoomed-out"` <-- assignment, not comparison. A good linter hooked up to your IDE would point out this.

Comment: `classList` returns the array of list and not single class.

Comment: I also tried ```className```, same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I changed my code to `if (imgClass.match("zoomed-out"))`. I honestly don't know what the difference is but it worked.

Comment: That is because the class can have more than one value like `class = "a b c"`. So when you did match, it worked.

Comment: But the element only had one class: ```zoomed-out```. And after it got changed to ```zoomed-in```, it didn't equal ```zoomed-out``` anymore so the way I understand it, it should've executed the second part of the code.